# Accessing obejct in object in json format in Typescript

Tags: angularjs, json, rest, angular-httpclient

I am consuming rest API from Angularjs 6. I have response like this from API in the console.

```
{
"flag": true,
"msg": "User credentials are matched",
"data": {
    "userId": 1234566,
    "password": "67899877@abdc",
    "firstName": "abcd",
    "lastName": "fghj",
    "email": "abcd@gmail.com",
    "status": 0,
    "role": 4
}
}
```

My angular code is mentioned below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

 @Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'getting-started-angular';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
   interface UserResponse {
      userId: Int16Array;
      password: String;
      firstname: String;
      lastname: String;
      status: Int16Array;
      role: Int16Array;
 }


  interface  UserValues {
flag: boolean;
msg: string;
 data: Object;
  }


 this.http.get<UserValues>('http://localhost:8080/v1/user? 
 userId=1234566&password=67899877@abdc').subscribe(result => {

  console.log(result);
console.log('flag:' + result.flag);
console.log('msg:' + result.msg);
console.log('firstname:' + result.data);
  });

  }
  }
```

Now i am able to access flag and message from console when i logged.
How can i access data:{} values from JSON response??

Comment: Have you tried `result.data.firstName`?

Comment: yes.but it is not giving me the result.

Comment: Property 'data' does not exist on type 'UserValues'. am getting this error

Answer (score 1):

Interfaces should be like this.

```
interface UserResponse {
      userId: Int16Array,
      password: string,
      firstName: string,
      lastName: string,
      email: string
      status: Int16Array,
      role: Int16Array,
 }

 interface  UserValues {
      flag: boolean;
      msg: string;
      data: UserResponse;
 }


console.log('firstname:' + result.data.firstName);
```

Comment: Thank you!!@fawad-mukhtar it's working. So the response in json and interface declartions in angular should be in same format??

Comment: As you used this.http.get<UserValues> statement. Here UserValues means you expect a response in this format. It should be the same

Comment: I got it.Thank you!! @fawad-mukhtar

Comment: One more question added to this.How can i display this JSON data in html file.Am using {{ result}} format.But it is not displaying the data.

Comment: result is a local variable. Declare a public property in class like you declared title variable. Then assign this local variable result to that one and use that in html template.

Comment: I have created public property as public data1:any; then i have stored local result in data1 as this.data1=result. then i have used in html as <p>{{data1.flag}}</p>.But it is giving me "ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'flag' of undefined"